# Can anybody explain the output of setImmediate and setTimeout in this code?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, setimmediate

What would be the output of `setImmediate` and `setTimeout` in the following code:

```
console.log("11111");

setImmediate(function A(){
console.log("2222");
});

console.log("3333");


setTimeout(function B(){

    console.log("4444");

},0);

console.log("5555");
```

Output:

```
11111
3333
5555
4444
2222
```

when i change time in `setTimeout` time to 10, output :

```
11111
3333
5555
2222
4444
```

Can anybody explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setImmediate()` is used to break up long running operations and run a callback function immediately after the browser has completed other operations such as events and display updates.

The `setTimeout()` calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. Which mean even if the browser has not completed yet, it is already working a function inside.

When you put `10` means, it will works only after **10 milliseconds** which is most likely your browser has completed already.